# What date does the Java keytool show?

Tags: java, certificate, keystore, keytool

Yesterday, I used `keytool` for listing our keystore like follows:

```
keytool -list -keystore src/keystore.p12 
Enter keystore password:  
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 5 entries

octopus, Jan 15, 2018, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): FE:B2:B7:C0:A7:CF:...
```

As there was a problem, I concluded that the first certificate has just expired. Today I'm getting

```
octopus, Jan 16, 2018, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): FE:B2:B7:C0:A7:CF:...
```

**Is `keytool` really meant for showing the current date or is it just joking???**

I though, the date was the "Not After" date, as it made sense. It can't be the date the entry was added or recently modified. I may be doing something wrong, but

- I'm sure that the date has changed as I can see in an email I sent yesterday
- I'm sure that the keystore did not change as it's tracked by git. I've even deleted it and checked it out again, no change
- I'm sure that the keystore hasn't changed since six months ago (and git agrees)
- other entries show different dates

---

The keytool provides no version information.

```
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: @AxelH Ours do, however they expire in a few years.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For JKS it IS the date the keystore entry was created or modified, but PKCS12 doesn't store that info so keytool (actually JCE IINM) just uses 'now'.

Note in recent updates of java 8 `KeyStore.getInstance("JKS")` actually reads both JKS and PKCS12; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47640052/2868801 . In java 9 PKCS12 becomes default.

To see the validity period (notBefore and notAfter) *in* the cert(s), along with a lot of other info you may not want, use `-v`

Comment: The funny thing is that `keytool` shows `Keystore type: JKS` ([which may or may not be right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45041311/keystore-does-not-work-on-java-9)], so the modification date should be there... but it isn't. Showing the current date is the most stupid idea, anyway.

Comment: The Keystore type is JKS, but the _file_ is PKCS12 (as indicated by the suffix) and the PKCS12 _file_ doesn't contain the timestamp(s). See my new comment on your prior Q, and the Q I linked in my answer.